# Flask SQLAlchemy Querying Object Not Reflecting Database

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to create a simple Flask application that utilizes Flask-SQLAlchemy and WTForms. The goal is to have a simple form that pushes information to the database when submitted and presents the current entries in the database at the bottom of the form. Ideally, the moment the form information is submitted, I would want the information that was pushed to the database to be immediately reflected on the same page.  Here is what I currently have:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://(REMOVED FOR QUESTION)/testing'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abcd'
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class ActivityPanel(FlaskForm):  #WTF FORM DEFINITION
    text_title = StringField('Text Info', validators=[InputRequired()])


class Alerts(UserMixin, db.Model):  #FLASK SQL ALCHEMY DEFINITION
    InputID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True)
    text_alert = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False, server_default="None")
db.create_all()

@app.route('/alerts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def alerts1():
    form = ActivityPanel()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        alert_object = Alerts(text_alert=form.text_title.data)
        db.session.add(alert_object)
        db.session.commit()
    database_pull = Alerts.query.all()
    return render_template('test.html', form = form, database_pull=database_pull)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The code for the template is the following:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('.static', filename='signin.css')}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/alerts">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Every time you click the submit button, it pushes to the database</h2>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.text_title) }}
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Push to database</button>
      </form>
    {% for query in database_pull %}
        <li>{{ query.InputID }}</li>
        <li>{{ query.text_alert }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

    </div> <!-- /container -->
{% endblock %}
```

As it currently stands, the main issue I am running into is the fact that the database query pull object that grabs all the content in the database only grabs and stores the information stored in the database the moment the flask program is launched. Once launched, even after I add more data to the database, the query object doesn't reflect the newly added information. I have to end up closing the application and restarting it for the object to update with the new database entries.

I was hoping someone could answer if there was an easy way for me to allow the database_pull object to grab the content from the database live rather than once at the beginning. Based on what I've read, this problem has to do with SQLAlchemy updating the state of the object once per transaction. I attempted to make the object expire/refresh the session but it didn't work with Flask-SQLAlchemy. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the surface this seems like the usual MySQL default isolation level (REPEATABLE READ) issue, but it's hard to say if it is actually to blame this time. It'd require connections not being returned to the pool properly at the end of a request, so transactions would be kept alive between them.

Comment: I see, so the transactions should be getting terminated but aren't? Is there a way I can manually terminate the transactions? I thought Flask-SQLAlchemy automatically terminated the transactions.

Comment: I guess it should be, and especially when you submit it should work as expected since you commit, which ends the transaction, so the subsequent query-all should start a new transaction that reads from a new snapshot.

Comment: Just tried your setup with Postgresql and repeatable read, but could not reproduce the issue. Running with `flask run`. Are you by any chance using some other method of running your server, perhaps process based or some such? Also have you run your application with SQLALCHEMY_ECHO set to True and checked that it rollbacks at the end of transactions?

Comment: Thanks for all the help llija, I have my MySQL database hosted on a digital ocean droplet away from the computer I am developing it on. The MySQL database is configured to allow access from connections outside the droplet itself(For testing purposes only). Might that have something to do with it? I don't believe i'm running my app in a special way.

Comment: Starting to think it might. Tested using a mysql docker container, and could not reproduce.